# How to access a variable within a struct within a struct

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct
{
    char Flight[10];                    
    int iRequested;                     
} Request;

typedef struct Node
{
    Request   request;                       
    struct Node *pNext;                     
} Node;
```

I've always been troubled with linked lists so as I'm writing this code Im having trouble accessing a a variable of a struct within a struct. I'm having errors compiling the way I try to go about this problem. How can I access a struct variable within a struct? using pointers preferably, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this-

```
typedef struct
{
    char Flight[10];                    
    int iRequested;                     
} Request;

typedef struct Node
{
    Request   request;                       
    struct Node *pNext;                     
} Node;


int main()
{

    Node mynode;

  mynode.request.iRequested=1;

 printf("iRequested is %d",mynode.request.iRequested);


}
```

**Result-**

> iRequested is 1

Comment: OP tagged the question as C, not C++: please write your solution in the correct language.